# Script para abrir una conexión con un servidor Apache y mantenerla abierta

Tags: bash

Necesito abrir una conexión persistente con un servidor web Apache durante 40 minutos.

El problema es que cuando ejecuto `nc $IP $PUERTO` realiza la conexión, devuelve el contenido HTML y la cierra inmediatamente después.

Es decir, cuando ejecuto el bucle me realiza una conexión diferente por cada `echo`.

Necesito que mantenga durante 40 minutos la misma conexión abierta.

He realizado el siguiente script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while (true); do
echo -n "$RANDOM " | nc $IP $PUERTO
done
```

Modificación realizada:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo /tmp/mi_fifo
while true
do
    # Lanzamos el proceso en segundo plano con el parámetro -N
    nc -n $IP $PUERTO < /tmp/mi_fifo &
    # Mantenemos abierto el descriptor 3
    exec 3> /tmp/mi_fifo
    # Escribimos el valor aleatorio al descriptor 3
    echo -n "$RANDOM " >&3
    # Esperamos 40 segundos
    sleep $((40 * 60))
    # Cerramos el descriptor, provocando el cierre de "nc"
    exec 3>& -
   kill $(ps aux | grep '[b]ash' | awk '{print $2}')
done
```

Comment: He redactado una nueva respuesta que mantiene correctamente establecida la conexión siempre y cuando no tengas un cortafuegos entre medias que descarte la conexión tras un tiempo de inactividad tan elevado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema está en que el `echo` está enviando un `EOF` a `nc` inmediatamente después de enviar el número aleatorio que has generado. En consecuencia `nc` cierra la conexión con el servidor si éste cerró su lado.

Para evitarlo podrías usar un [archivo especial FIFO](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FIFO-Special-Files.html). Este tipo de archivos solo enviarán un `EOF` si todos los procesos que están escribiendo en él cierran sus descriptores de archivo.

Entonces, deberemos mantener abierto dicho archivo durante los segundos que necesites haciendo uso de `exec` de la siguiente manera:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo /tmp/mi_fifo
while true
do
    # Lanzamos el proceso en segundo plano con el parámetro -N
    nc -N $IP $PUERTO < /tmp/mi_fifo &
    # Guardamos el PID del proceso puesto en segundo plano
    PID=$!
    # Mantenemos abierto el descriptor 3
    exec 3> /tmp/mi_fifo
    # Escribimos el valor aleatorio al descriptor 3
    echo -n "$RANDOM " >&3
    # Esperamos 40 segundos
    sleep $((40 * 60))
    # Cerramos el descriptor, provocando el cierre de "nc"
    exec 3>& -
    # Si no ha muerto, matamos al proceso "nc"
    kill $PID
done
```

---

El parámetro `-N` se usa para forzar a `nc` a finalizar la conexión tras recibir el `EOF`:

> **-N**
>
> shutdown(2) the network socket after `EOF` on the input. Some servers require this to finish their work.

En castellano:

> **-N**
>
> cierra(2) el socket de red tras el `EOF` en la entrada. Algunos servidores requieren esto para finalizar su trabajo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Voy a probarlo.

En este caso, debería de cambiar 'sleep $((40 * 60))' por 'sleep $((2400 * 60))' cierto?
Deseo que se mantenga abierta la misma conexión NC durante 40 minutos.

Comment: Cierto, disculpa.
Muchas gracias por la aclaración. Voy a probarlo!

Comment: He probado el método, pero ' exec 3>& -' no cierra la conexión nc.
Lo he comprobado reduciendo el tiempo a 1 minuto.
He añadido 'kill $(ps aux | grep '[b]ash' | awk '{print $2}')' justo debajo de 'exec 3>&-'.

Ahora tras 1 minuto me devuelve un 'Terminated' y cierra la conexión.

El archivo 'mi_fifo' está vacío. ¿Debe ser así?.

Comment: El archivo `mi_fifo` es un archivo especial, si no hay procesos escribiendo en él no hay datos que salgan de él. ¿Podrías compartir en tu pregunta el script que estás usando? Hice una actualización para agregar el parámetro `-N`, ¿lo has incluido?

Comment: Añadido! Muchas gracias!

Comment: El fallo que has cometido es que has puesto `-n` en **minúsculas**, cuando en mi código está en **mayúsculas** `-N`. En linux es MUY IMPORTANTE respetar la capitalización de las cosas. Ya puestos, he editado la respuesta para enseñarte la manera correcta de matar un proceso que se lanzó en segundo plano. Se usa `$!` para obtener el PID y, posteriormente, se usa ese valor para matarlo con un `kill`. No es necesario agregar complejas búsquedas de procesos, etc. PD: He borrado comentarios anteriores para limpiar un poco la respuesta.

Comment: Si pongo -N en mayúsculas me devuelve el siguiente error: nc: invalid option -- 'N'
This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available.------->


Tengo instalado ambos paquetes, tanto netcat-openbsd como netcat-traditional

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo y versión estás usando? ¿Qué versión de `nc` estás usando?

Comment: Lo he ejecutado desde otro servidor y el parametro -N funciona.
Al parecer el script realiza lo que necesito. Voy a hacer varias pruebas.
Muchas gracias Oscar, si tuviera algún problema en las pruebas que voy a realizar hablamos de nuevo si te parece. Un saludo.

Comment: Si la versión que usas de `nc` es muy antigua no tendrá el parámetro `-N`, por lo que puedes quitar la opción ya que será el `kill` el que finalice la ejecución del `nc`. ¡Suerte!

Comment: ¡Marcada como respuesta correcta!